# Functional Pearl: Implementing trace in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, tying-the-knot

Ross Paterson: [Arrows and Computation](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/%7Eross/papers/fop.html) introduces the [`trace`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traced_monoidal_category) function (on page 11):

```hs
trace :: ((a, c) -> (b, c)) -> a -> b
trace f a = let (b, c) = f (a, c) in b
```

The `trace` function is useful for modularizing the magic feedback step in [circular programs](https://wiki.haskell.org/Circular_programming). For example, consider Richard Bird's famous [`repmin`](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2697826) function which finds the minimum leaf value of a tree **and** creates an identical tree with every leaf value replaced by the minimum leaf value, both in a single pass by making clever use of lazy evaluation and local recursion (as provided by `letrec`):

```hs
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Tree Tree deriving Show

repmin :: Tree -> Tree
repmin = trace repmin'

repmin' :: (Tree, Int) -> (Tree, Int)
-- put the minimum value m into the leaf and return the old value n as the minimum
repmin' (Leaf n, m) = (Leaf m, n)
-- copy the minimum value m into both the left and right subtrees and
-- set the minimum value m to the minimum of both the left and right subtrees
repmin' (Node l r, m) = let (l', lmin) = repmin' l m in
                        let (r', rmin) = repmin' r m in
                        (Node l' r', lmin `min` rmin)
```

Anyway, I was wondering how to implement the `trace` function in JavaScript such that we can implement `repmin` as follows:

```js
const Leaf = (value) => ({ tag: "Leaf", value });

const Node = (left, right) => ({ tag: "Node", left, right });

const repmin = trace(function repmin(tree, min) {
    switch (tree.tag) {
    case "Leaf":
        return [Leaf(min), tree.value];
    case "Node":
        const [left,  lmin] = repmin(tree.left,  min);
        const [right, rmin] = repmin(tree.right, min);
        return [Node(left, right), Math.min(lmin, rmin)];
    }
});
```

In order to implement `trace` we need local recursion as provided by `letrec` so that we can write something like:

```js
const trace = (f) => (a) => {
    const [b, c] = f(a, c);
    return b;
};
```

I originally thought of making `c` a promise. However, that changes the semantics of `trace`. So, can you think of a way to implement `trace` in JavaScript without changing its semantics?

Comment: You can't really do that, but maybe you can fake it with proxy objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you only need lazy evaluation because assignments in JavaScript are like `letrec`. Lazy evaluation is generally implemented using [thunks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk). Hence, you can implement `trace` as follows:

```js
const trace = (f) => (a) => {
    const [b, c] = f(a, () => c);
    return b;
};
```

Using this definition of `trace`, the `repmin` function can remain the same:

```js
const repmin = trace(function repmin(tree, min) {
    switch (tree.tag) {
    case "Leaf":
        return [Leaf(min), tree.value];
    case "Node":
        const [left,  lmin] = repmin(tree.left,  min);
        const [right, rmin] = repmin(tree.right, min);
        return [Node(left, right), Math.min(lmin, rmin)];
    }
});
```

However, you'd want to make your data constructors possibly lazy using getters:

```js
const descOf = (value) =>
    typeof value === "function" && value.length === 0 ?
        { enumerable: true, get: value } :
        { enumerable: true, value };

const Leaf = (value) => Object.defineProperties({ tag: "Leaf" }, {
    value: descOf(value),
});

const Node = (left, right) => Object.defineProperties({ tag: "Node" }, {
    left: descOf(left),
    right: descOf(right),
});
```

Putting it all together:

```js
const trace = (f) => (a) => {
    const [b, c] = f(a, () => c);
    return b;
};

const descOf = (value) =>
    typeof value === "function" && value.length === 0 ?
        { enumerable: true, get: value } :
        { enumerable: true, value };

const Leaf = (value) => Object.defineProperties({ tag: "Leaf" }, {
    value: descOf(value),
});

const Node = (left, right) => Object.defineProperties({ tag: "Node" }, {
    left: descOf(left),
    right: descOf(right),
});

const repmin = trace(function repmin(tree, min) {
    switch (tree.tag) {
    case "Leaf":
        return [Leaf(min), tree.value];
    case "Node":
        const [left,  lmin] = repmin(tree.left,  min);
        const [right, rmin] = repmin(tree.right, min);
        return [Node(left, right), Math.min(lmin, rmin)];
    }
});

const show = (tree) => {
    switch (tree.tag) {
    case "Leaf": return `Leaf(${tree.value})`;
    case "Node": return `Node(${show(tree.left)}, ${show(tree.right)})`;
    }
}

const tree = Node(Node(Leaf(1), Leaf(2)), Node(Leaf(3), Leaf(4)));

console.log("Input: ", show(tree));

console.log("Output:", show(repmin(tree)));
```

The only problem is that you won't be able to write functions like:

```js
const sqr = trace((x, y) => [y * y, x]);
```

This is because the `*` operator is not lazy. Hence, you would have to define a lazy `mul` function:

```js
const trace = (f) => (a) => {
    const [b, c] = f(a, () => c);
    return b;
};

const evaluate = (value) =>
    typeof value === "function" && value.length === 0 ?
        value() : value;

const mul = (a, b) => () => evaluate(a) * evaluate(b);

const sqr = trace((x, y) => [mul(y, y), x]);

console.log(evaluate(sqr(10)));
```

Hope that helps.